# Convert multiple rows into a single comma separated string without XML

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to combine data from multiple rows into a single comma separated string without using the XML function as it is not supported.

Here is an example:

**ID    Food**

1   Apple

1   orange

2   wine

2   whiskey

2   beer

3   rice

3   wheat

3   maize

3   quinoa

Note that number rows per id is not fixed

Output:

**ID    Foods**

1   Apple, orange

2   wine, whiskey, beer

3   rice, wheat, maize, quinoa

Comment: hi, can you be more precise? what database? (oracle, microsoft .. etc)

Comment: As mentioned by @F.Lazarescu, stating what _is_ supported (by mentioning specific RDBMS and version) would be more helpful that mentioning what's _not_ supported.

Comment: Basically read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Apologies everyone - I am new to this platform and made an error there. I have now tagged the platform i am using - bigquery

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Just upvoted your answer as it was really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
select id, string_agg(food) as foods
from `project.dataset.table`
group by id
```